# Border-Collapse in Material Design Table

Tags: css, angular, material-design

How to add something like that:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

in Material Design Table?

When I add border code to **.mat-cell**:

```
.mat-cell {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

in some places the border looks like 2px.

I would like to add a border because I would like to change the color at the hover.

**Stackblitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmnxfa-jmgwnp

Comment: Do you want to have the hover effect on the row, cell or both?

Comment: On all row. But material design table dont have "border-collapse" and in some places the border looks like 2px NOT 1px...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `border-collapse` on `<div>`s. So you'll need to use negative margins instead and bring the hovered item on top:

```css
.mat-cell {
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
}

.mat-row {
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.mat-row:hover { 
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://angular-bmnxfa-r7x93a.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

It is now recommended to use mat-table as a directive on an actual table.

- https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

The flexbox approach is now mostly considered the "old" way of doing things. Many things don’t work quite right with it.

- https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-code-display-flex-code-

As such, if you are using a table, then applying the style is just a matter of... applying it I guess.

```html
<table mat-table class="myClassWithBorderCollapse" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this by extending the default theme and using `components.MuiTable.styleOverrides.root.borderCollapse`:

```
import { experimental_extendTheme as extendMuiTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

const theme = extendMuiTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTable: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderCollapse: 'separate',
          borderSpacing: 0
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Then be sure to wrap your component in `ThemeProvider` as indicated in the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/).